# Mac clients accessing a Windows NTFS share resetting permissions at deeper folder levels. Why?

Tags: windows-server-2008, network-share, mac, ntfs, server-message-block

Here's the setup:

- Windows 2008 server
- `c:\share` folder with the following permissions (read, read/write are not important at this point, I don't think):

  - User1
  - User2
- `c:\share\add_user3` folder with the following permissions:

  - User3 (explicitly added at this folder level)
  - User1 (inherited from `c:\share`)
  - User2 (inherited from `c:\share`)
- Share called `share` for `c:\share` with read/write permissions for the server-local admins
- Mixed client environment:

  - Windows XP clients
  - Windows 7 clients
  - Mac clients (OSX v10.8.4)

Windows client behavior (both XP and Windows 7):

- User creates a file `c:\share\test.txt`
- Effective permissions on that file are inherited from the folder:

  - User1
  - User2
- User creates a file `c:\share\add_user3\test.txt`
- Effective permissions on that file are inherited from the folder:

  - User1
  - User2
  - User3

Mac client behavior:

- User creates a file `c:\share\test.txt`
- Effective permissions on that file:

  - User1
  - User2
- User creates a file `c:\share\add_user3\test.txt` OR User edits an existing file `c:\share\add_user3\test.txt` that was created on a Windows client
- Effective permissions on that file become:

  - User1
  - User2

It's like the Mac clients are taking the NTFS permissions at the share folder level ( `c:\share`) and applying it directly to `c:\share\add_user3\test.txt`.  The permissions from  `c:\share\add_user3` are not being honored/inherited.

The Mac client users are all local admins on the server (and therefore have full control).  This is necessary from an operational standpoint as all clients (even the Mac users) need to access the server in an administrative capacity (IIS admin mostly).

I'm a Windows guy primarily, so it appears that the Macs are "wrong" but perhaps this is just differing behavior (i.e. there's no "standard" here that is being violated).  Any ideas why this is happening?  And, given that we want the permissions to behave like the Windows clients, any ideas on how to enforce this on the Mac side?

### Follow-up answers

- As for different editors, this was tried with XCode and also TextEdit.  Same behavior in both.
- After testing with a user who was *not* in local admins, it looks like the appropriate permissions were applied/retained, *except* for the following behavior:

  - When the user creates a file from a Windows machine, the file owner is set to the account of the user in question
  - When the user creates a file from a Mac, the file owner is set to `MACHINE\Administrators`

Comment: What editor is being used on the Mac clients? Some programs do silly things like storing the new version as a temp file *in a different folder*, then deleting the original and moving the formerly-temp file into its place; this can result in the new file inheriting permissions from the temp location, not its "real" location. Also, can you test with a Mac client that isn't a server admin, and at least find out if that's part of the problem?

Comment: @GordonDavisson, thanks for the response.  First question answered in an edit above.  I'll get back to you on the second question.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, second question answered above

Comment: I tried this on Mavericks and the problem still exists.  I also tried Thursby Software's DAVE, which is an SMB replacement for OS X, and it still has the same problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by something [Apple calls "safe save](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4149)".  When a Mac saves a file on an SMB share, it actually writes the file to a hidden folder named *.TemporaryItems* in the root of the share, deletes the original (if it exists), then moves the file to the actual folder.  Since the saved file is new, it has a new owner, with permissions that were inherited from *.TemporaryItems*.

The solution I'm using is simple: **remove write permissions for *.TemporaryItems***.  This seems to disable safe save.

I've read that [creating *com.apple.desktopservices* with the "DSDontWriteNetworkStores" attribute](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1629) will stop the clients from creating *.TemporaryItems*, but in my experience, this doesn't work on OS X 10.8 and newer.